# Use of being in English

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the use of **being** in the following sentence:

> He denied any paper being leaked.

In my perception, **"being"** is used for state or for any action which is currently happening or happened in the past. Did he want to say that there is no paper leaking?

However if I say:

> He denied any paper has been leaked.

or

> He denied any paper is leaked.

or

> He denied any paper leaking.

are those the same?

One more example; please explain, in this context:

> "Accusing Narendra Modi of **getting** scared of Kejriwal and initiating police action"

can I use *being* instead of *getting*:

> "Accusing Narendra Modi of **being** scared of Kejriwal and initiating police action"

Comment: "He denied any paper leaking." can sound like you mean papers that have water dripping out of them! As J.R. points out in his answer, "paper-leaking" would be better.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's set a context:

> **Reporter**: Mr. President, has any paper been leaked by your office?
>   **President**: Absolutely not.

Later, in the newsroom:

> **News Anchor**: At a press conference yesterday, the president was asked if his office had leaked any papers, but *he denied any paper being leaked*.

The word *denied* is in the past tense, so I think the sentence sounds quite natural when referring to an event in the past (in this case, the press conference, and, more specifically, the president's denial at the press conference).

Now, for your paraphrases; first, these two:

> He denied any paper has been leaked.
>   He denied any paper is leaked.

I think I would prefer:

> He denied any paper **was** leaked.

because it seems like "He denied" refers to an event firmly entrenched in the past. The way you have written the sentences (with "has been leaked" and "is leaked"), that refers to a current state of affairs; in other words: no paper was leaked back then, and no paper has been leaked even now. Your sentences are not ungrammatical, but they just sound a little bit off.

The news might also report:

> He denies that any papers have been leaked.

if the president has made such denials multiple times. In that case, the sentence is a way of saying, "He keeps on denying that any papers have been leaked."

About:

> He denied any paper leaking.

I'd suggest avoiding that one. Again, it's not so bad that I'd call it ungrammatical, but the phrase "paper leaking" doesn't sound idiomatic. I might even suggest a hyphen: *He denied any paper-leaking.*

As for your second question, when dealing with emotions, the only difference between *getting happy* and *being happy* is that the former implies a change of state. If I *get scared*, that means I wasn't scared before, but if I *am scared*, I may have become scared recently, or I may be a paranoid person by nature.

Answer (score 0):

**Generally,** when we use *being done*, it talks about something that has happened recently i.e. the process is complete (again, exceptions are there - *Being built in 1930, the bridge is still rock-steady. It's surprising!*).

*been* and *being* are [different](http://www.grammar-monster.com/easily_confused/being_been.htm).

All three ways you used **almost mean the same thing** - *He does not agree that any paper is leaked.*

> He denied any paper has been leaked - more recent...or at least its effect is still there. 
>   He denied any paper is leaked - present perfect meaning the same. 
>   He denied any paper leaking - this emphasizes more on the 'process of paper leaking'. And, unless you **read it,** it sounds like 'paper leaking' is used as a noun (though hyphen would make better sense: *paper-leaking*).